# Vibrate from OnLongClickListener

Tags: android, android-vibration

Maybe someone can explain me, how to vibrate from OnLongClickListener properly. In method below the vibration is very short. 
If I set `return false;` vibration lasts for 5000ms as expected, BUT `OnClickListener` is fired.

How should I vibrate from OnLongClickListener for whole period, and not fire `OnClickListener`?

```
final Vibrator x = (Vibrator) getParent()
            .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        x.vibrate(5000);
        return true;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a click event is triggered, it is passed down to the lowest handler available (unless someone interrupted). In your case, a long click event is first passed to the `OnLongClickListener`. If that listener returns `true`, it basically announces that this click event has been handled. If it returns `false`, it a announces that the click event was not handled by it, and that's why the event is passed along one level higher to the handler above it in the hierarchy, in your case, the `OnClickListener`.

That's why returning `false` isn't the way to go, because you do want to handle the long click event.

What about creating a background thread or an `ASyncTask` for the vibration itself.
Something Like:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    getHandler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            x.vibrate(5000);           
        }

    });
    return true;
}
```

*I didn't test the code but it should be fine.*

Answer (score 0):

You could set a timer to run for the period of the vibration, and only once it has timed out, return True. A bit fudgy, but it should work.